# Magento 2.2.2 bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function

Tags: magento2, jquery

I am Using Magento 2.2.2.
I have inserted this code in the Block i.e Content>Block
when wei click on the Ask an Expert image , The Modal popup should appear. But currently its not showing popup, the error is show.

```
<div class="call-us">
    <div class="call-us-content">
        <a id="click-me" href="#"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/icon/askanExpert.png"}}" alt="Ask an Expert" style="height: 50px; position: relative;" /></a>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="popup-mpdal"  style="display:none;">
<br>
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/icon/IconAskExpert.png"}}" alt="Ask an Expert" />
<br/>
<p style="font-size: 17px;">Mon-Sat (10 AM to 6 PM)</p>
<p style="font-size: 18px;">Get Free Consultation From Our Certified Expert</p><br>
<p style="color: #2B375C;font-size: 35px;"><em class="fa fa-phone" style=" padding-right: 10px;    position: relative;
    top: 2px;"></em><a style="    color: #76c705;" href="tel:0120-4673988">0120-4673988</a></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
    require(
        [
     'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
            '!domReady'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
               modalLeftMargin: 45,
                title: 'Consult our Expert',
  modalClass: 'ask-our-expert',
 clickableOverlay: true,
  buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]

            };


 var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));

            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 

             $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");

            });

        }
    );

</script>
```

Comment: try to put that code in PHTML and call that PHTML in BLOCK

Comment: I have inserted that code in PHTML file and after that call that phtml file in block. But its not working. Still its getting an error... bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function

Comment: have you tried without ` xml="space"`?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with or without  ` xml="space"`.

Comment: I hope you have not added or update your new  `bootstrap.min.js` file. can you share website URL?

Comment: am using the paid theme. In which the bootstrap version is 3.3.6 and jquery 1.12.4 and jquery UI 1.10.4

Comment: bootstrap version 4 is not compatible with our paid theme. So, is there any way to resolve this with the bootstrap version 3.3.6

Comment: Actually, Magento 2 providing those files, maybe you are getting that error because of not loading basic `bootstrap.min.js` or conflict with basic magento `bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Can we help me out. am getting stuck in this.

Comment: Is there any why to use swipe slider when we click on the anchor tag. and how is it possible

Comment: you need to use basic Magento  `bootstrap.min.js` file

Comment: @DeveloperAccount Same error is comming to me. You got any solution for this?

Comment: Same problem here, any solutions?

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when I was using the "modal" function of the Magento-UI.
It was fixed using a noConflict function from bootstrap.

```
$.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
```

For example, in my case, I got this issue using the Magemenu extension so it was fixed the following way

```
 require(['jquery',"Ves_All/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min"], function ($) {
    $.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
    ...
    ...
 });
```

After that, I could use the modal of the Magento-UI without problems.

Comment: Hi Juan, after this fix do I have to use it like this: $("#popup-mpdal").bsModal("openModal"); OR like this $("#popup-mpdal").$.fn.bsModal("openModal");

Comment: I got this error: $.fn.modal.noConflict is not a function

Comment: Hi Gonzalo Gutiérrez, you have to use $("#popup-mpdal").bsModal("show");
You can check the bootstrap document https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.5/docs/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: has same issue and your solution works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never

Thought it would be best if I propose a complete solution here which works for me.

Firstly adding the following line of code at the top of your JS file (widget, component,...):

```javascript
$.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
```

Like this:

```javascript
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, modal, $t, mageUrl) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();

    // more code
});
```

Secondly, initiate a modal like usual, no changes to this procedure:

```javascript
modal(options, $('#modal-id'));
```

Lastly, call a modal like this:

```javascript
$("#modal-id").bsModal("show");
```

instead of

```
$("#modal-id").modal("openModal");
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by lowering down the bootstrap version

Current one :  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js

before I was using 3.3.7

Comment: I am facing the same issue and I am already using 3.3.6